# Could anyone explain drawrect and context animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, cgcontext, setneedsdisplay

I'm quitely new for the `iOS`, so I don't know much of it.
I know how to make `UIView` (and its childviews) but I don't know about `drawRect`

I make a class which inherits from `UIView` and make subviews in `initWithFrame` method.
I want to draw a `NSString` using `CGContext` after adding `subViews` and move it outside of view after 5 seconds.

Could anyone explain when `drawRect` is called and how to move it?

Answer (score 1):

This code helps you to draw a `NSString` which was stored before in **_content**:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [_content drawInRect:rectForFrame
                withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontMedium size:15.0f]
           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
               alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
}
```

To let the element slide out, you would have to call a `NSTimer` after your `UIView` was shown (Maybe with a delay using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`) and change the attributes of the `CGRect` you want to write the `NSString` inside. You can just setup a method which will be called by your `NSTimer` in a specific interval which also updates the `UIView`.

```
- (void)updateView{

  //create a rect
  rectForFrame = CGRectMake....;
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to draw the string and then start an [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). Start a 5 second timer, and when it fires, then you can move it.

As for when `-drawRect:` is called - it's called whenever your view needs to be updated. It will be called when your view is first displayed by the OS. After that, it will usually be called when it changes size or shape, or when your code calls `[myView setNeedsDisplay:YES]`, which tells the OS to update it.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you mean I don't need to call drawrect directly (also overide) and draw the string using NSTimer correct?

Comment: You would draw the string initially in your `-drawRect:` method, and then start your timer. When the timer fires, change your state so you know that the timer fired. Then call `-setNeedsDisplay:YES`, and your `-drawRect:` method will get called again. When you notice the state is different, you can start the animation.